# Error accediendo a estilo: Resource is not public. (at 'style' with value '@android:style/Widget.NumberPicker')

Tags: android

El estilo que quiero usar es el siguiente,pero me da error  de recurso no publico

```
 <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/pruebaNumber"
        style="@android:style/Widget.NumberPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7" />
```

Comment: Tendras que utilizar otro recurso ya que el sistema lo tiene como privado. Puedes dar una idea de lo que buscas exactamente? Asi podriamos ayudarte a encontrar uno parecido.

Comment: simplemente me gusto ese estilo, el cual lo trae el android studio,lo que no entiendo, es que,si te lo muestra todo bien,pq a la hora de compilar no puede acceder a el,por eso creo que debe de haber alguna forma para si hacerlo.Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: [Existe muchos otros que puedes utilizar](https://www.google.com.do/search?newwindow=1&biw=1536&bih=759&ei=HTI5WpPiAs-ujwPl8Ij4AQ&q=NumberPicker+github&oq=NumberPicker+github&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1.559.3433.0.3538.13.11.2.0.0.0.157.1013.0j7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..4.9.1017...0i20i263k1j0i67k1.0.3XHyBMx768w) como por ejemplo este [Number Picker](https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker), muy bueno y facil de utilizar.

Comment: si ese es que tenia,pero no me gustaba que tuviera los numeros visible arriba y abajo por eso me puse a ver los stilos y encontre ese,ahh,no solo no puedo acceder a ese sino a ninguno,como Widget.Holo.NumberPicker y otros ,me da el mismo error,solo puedo dejarlo en none

Comment: Number Picker no tiene los números arriba y abajo sino que son 2 diferentes con  orientaciones diferentes es todo.

Comment: ok, no conozco mucho del tema ya que empece estudiar android sola hace un mes,pero si hay alguna forma de que quede como a mi me gusta hasmelo saber ,q solo se muestre un solo numero y de alguna forma el usuario pueda cambiarlo,de otra forma utilizare un spinner y ya jeje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza [`Number Picker`](https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker). Para eso harás lo siguiente:

En tu graddle de la aplicacion agrega lo siguiente dentro de `dependencies`:

```
 compile 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.4'
```

Sincronizas el proyecto. Luego agregas el `NumberPicker` a tu vista:

```
<com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/number_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:np_width="64dp"
    app:np_height="180dp"
    app:np_dividerColor="@color/colorPrimary" // color que lo divide
    app:np_formatter="@string/number_picker_formatter"
    app:np_max="59" // maximo de los numeros del picker
    app:np_min="0" // minimo de los numeros
    app:np_selectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" // color del numero seleccionado
    app:np_selectedTextSize="@dimen/selected_text_size" // tamaño del numero seleccionado
    app:np_textColor="@color/colorPrimary" // color de los numeros
    app:np_textSize="@dimen/text_size" // tamano por defecto de lo snumeros
    app:np_value="3" /> // valor seleccionado
```

La oritacion por defecto es vertical pero si lo deseas horizontal, solo agregas lo siguente:

```
np_orientation="horizonal"
```